# Android Jelly Bean 4.2.2- blocked system access

Tags: android, security, android-4.2-jelly-bean, blocked, samsung-knox

First of all I'm not technically savvy, so please bear with me.

I just purchased a Samsung S4 Mini with factory installed Jelly Bean 4.2.2. Immediately upon setup, I started receiving a notification message before I even downloaded any applications on the device as follows: "An application attempted to access system on your device without authorization. This attempt has been blocked. Deleting applications obtained from unauthorized sources may improve security."

After downloading Whatsapp from Google Play, every time I try to change the profile picture or upload a picture in a conversation, I receive a pop-up error message as follows: "Failed to load image data, please try again later," and a notification as follows: "WhatsApp attempted to access system on your device without authorization. This attempt has been blocked."

The same thing keeps happening with Facebook, True Caller, and pretty much every application that I launch.

I formatted my external storage micro SD, uninstalled WhatsApp and re-installed it, but that didn't work.

After an exhaustive search online and through various forums, including contacting Samsung, I could not find a solution.

I checked Security settings under Settings/Permissions/Security and made sure Security Level is set to Normal (the other option is High). I also checked the Credential Storage under Settings/Security/Credential Storage and could not figure out a solution.

I hope my question is concise and clear enough. How can I resolve this security issue?

Answer (score 0):

That's the KNOX warning. Update to 4.3 and hopefully it will be addressed.

Comment: Thank you @meatspace. I tried that, but unfortunately, in the middle of the upgrade, a warning pop-up window written in South Korean flashes on the screen and the upgrade is halted, leaving me dumbfounded and without any recourse.

Comment: Hopefully someone at your local Samsung store speaks Korean! That would be my next move, especially with a new/factory device.